# Add object to arrayList without overwritting it

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
public ArrayList<Player> addPlayer(String playerName, int playerWorth,   int playerSpent)
{
    Player newPlayer = new Player();
    newPlayer.setPlayerName(playerName);
    newPlayer.setPlayerWorth(playerWorth);
    newPlayer.setPlayerSpent(playerSpent);
    playerAList.add(newPlayer);
    return playerAList;
}
```

How can I access the above method from a different class without having to overwrite the object in the `arraylist`? I am trying to create a new `Player` and set its name/worth/spent and then add it to an `arraylist` of `playerAList` instead of overwriting it.

Comment: yes you can! simply check this yourself

Comment: You probably need to rephrase your question. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: The above [`ArrayList.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) doesn't overwrite items in the list. If you're experiencing a problem, it might lie somewhere else, e.g. in `Player`.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it should be rephrased to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry guys the problem was not that it was overriding, the above code was correct, but that in my constructor i was recreating the PlayerList ArrayList that holds all players. It took me 3 hours to figure it out but nevertheless it was great feeling once I found the problem. Thanks for your help anyway. Case closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to place unique object in your `ArrayList`. But `ArrayList` dose not override the earlier item when you add a new item which perfectly resemble with the earlier one. `ArrayList` keeps all the duplicate item. If you don't want to keep the duplicate item then you may use `HashSet` (with overriding of `equals()` method and `hashCode()`  method). But If you still want to use `ArrayList`, in this situation you may follow these steps:

**1.** Override your `Player` class `equals()` method. Override you equals method for those property for which you want to identify the uniqueness of your players.
**2.** Before adding to `ArrayList` use `ArrayList.contains()` method to evaluate whether an item already exist in the `ArrayList` -

```
Player newPlayer = new Player();
newPlayer.setPlayerName(playerName);
newPlayer.setPlayerWorth(playerWorth);
newPlayer.setPlayerSpent(playerSpent);

if(!playerAList.contains(newPlayer)){
   playerAList.add(newPlayer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList objects don't overwrite unless you specifically tell them to, they just shift the contents when you insert data into them.

That being said, a good way to access underlying data structures without actually tampering with them is an iterator
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm